# How to post text on friends wall using latest facebook sdk in IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, facebook-sharer

How to post a link or text on friends wall using Xcode 5? Some methods are depreciated in facebook SDK. Am using following code to post on friend's wall.

```
NSMutableDictionary *parmaDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];
[parmaDic setObject:link forKey:@"link"];            // if you want send picture
[parmaDic setObject:@"NAME" forKey:@"name"];         // if you want to display name
[parmaDic setObject:message forKey:@"description"];  // if you want to display  description
[parmaDic setObject:@"FRIEND_FACEBOOK_ID" forKey:@"to"];
[parmaDic setObject:@"LOGO_URL" forKey:@"picture"];  // if you want to send App logo

[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil parameters:parmaDic handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)  {
    if (error) {

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post on friends wall by using `FBWebDialogs` class of `Facebook SDK`. For that you need friends facebook id in parameters in dictionary as below

```
    NSMutableDictionary *parmaDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];
    [parmaDic setObject:link forKey:@"link"];            // if you want send picture
    [parmaDic setObject:@"NAME" forKey:@"name"];         // if you want to display name
    [parmaDic setObject:message forKey:@"description"];  // if you want to display  description
    [parmaDic setObject:@"FRIEND_FACEBOOK_ID" forKey:@"to"];
    [parmaDic setObject:@"LOGO_URL" forKey:@"picture"];  // if you want to send App logo

    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil parameters:parmaDic handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)  {
        if (error) {

           // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
           // NSLog(@"Error sending request.");

        } else {

                if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {

                    // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                    //    NSLog(@"User canceled request.");

                } else {    

                        //   NSLog(@"Successfully Invited.");

                  }
               }
         }];
```

Comment: See, User must have accepted "publish_actions" permission before execute above code.

Comment: Still i've doubt , can you please explain about publish_actions.

Comment: For post anything on facebook, User must accept publish_actions permission. This permission should be asked when you open session while login

Comment: @MANCHIKANTIKRISHNAKISHORE : No.. You must pass only one friend ID at time